# geometry of standard book class

Tags: geometry

I started using the `geometry` package in order to make the title page for a document that will probably never be printed (and even if so I do not have the cover at the moment, not would I like to work on that with the current speed of iterations) centered. Nevertheless I would prefer the standard geometry of the book class for all the rest of the document.

What are the correct parameters for `\newgeometry` to return to `book` standard after the title page. Currently I have

```
\newgeometry{hmarginratio=2:3}
```

which I think is quite a bit different. Or can I not use geometry at all if I like the behaviour of the standard book class for some part of a document?

Comment: Use `\restoregeometry` or better, save the current geometry with `\savegeometry{foo}` and restore it later on, after `\newgeometry` usage at 'any' place with `\loadgeometry{foo}`, where `foo` is just a symbolic name. The saving allows for multiple switches to other `geometry` setups in between, if needed

Answer (score 2):

Thx, the first helped me to find the solution and the second would be an alternative solution. Using

```
\usepackage[pass]{geometry} %does not change anything
\newgeometry{hmarginratio=1:1} %centered title page
\maketitle

\restoregeometry %back to normal
```